# Как преобразовать аудиофайл из stereo в mono на Android?

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Нужно преобразовать аудиофайл(mp3/ogg) в моно. Пробую, как в этом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371277/8663875

```
private void StereoToMono(InputStream in, File file)
{
    try {
        byte[] stereoSamples = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

        //output array, which will contain the mono signal
        byte[] monoSamples= new byte[stereoSamples.length/2];
        //length of the .wav-file header-> 44 bytes
        final int HEADER_LENGTH=44;

        //additional counter
        int k=0;


        for(int i=0; i< monoSamples.length;i++){
            //skip the header andsuperpose the samples of the left and right channel
            if(k>HEADER_LENGTH){
                monoSamples[i]= (byte) ((stereoSamples[i*2]+ stereoSamples[(i*2)+1])/2);
            }
            k++;
        }

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        bos.write(monoSamples);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

После такого преобразования не воспроизводится файл. Может есть какие-то готовые библиотеки?

Comment: Кстати, исходный файл может быть моно изначально

Comment: Хм.... а с каких пор семплы без хидера называются Wav-файлом? Более того, с mp3/ogg такой трюк, который вы делаете (а вы делаете это для Wav-файлов) - не прокатит. Кто расшифровывать данные будет при чтении, и кто их сжимать будет при записи? В вашем коде нет сжатия... вы смотрели спецификацию mp3/ogg?

Comment: Вы бы ещё спросили, "как подправить программу? Открываю в блокноте exe-файл, пишу print 'hello world'; и программа больше не работает"

Comment: @test123 не смотрел, но догадывался, что все не так просто, сейчас глянул. А что не так в моем вопросе? Мне нужен или готовый алгоритм или библиотека, которая будет работать на Android. javax.sound.sampled - не поддерживается на Android. Есть ли какие-нибудь аналоги?

Comment: Вроде как, у всех гугл одинаковый... https://github.com/naman14/TAndroidLame/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/naman14/tandroidlame/Mp3AudioRecordActivity.java Запись, соответственно тут: https://github.com/naman14/TAndroidLame/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/naman14/tandroidlame/EncodeActivity.java

Comment: @test123 Гугл в основном выдает сервисы-конвертеры. Нашел https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter но там не поддерживается ogg. В примере, который Вы скинули, из wav в mp3. А как из mp3 в mp3?